# Symfony2 - Catch Exception on $em->remove()

Tags: symfony, exception, doctrine-orm, doctrine, entitymanager

I am trying to catch an exception while executing:

```
try {
    $em->remove($education);
    $em->flush();
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    var_dump($e->getMessage());
    die;
}
```

I also tried `\Exception` and `\Doctrine\ORM\ORMException`, but none of them worked.

Instead of dumping exception message I get the same error I am trying to avoid catching exception:

> [3/3] ForeignKeyConstraintViolationException: An exception occurred
>   while executing 'DELETE FROM trainee_education WHERE id = ?' with
>   params [2]:
>
> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or
>   update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`trainingexperience`.`internship`, CONSTRAINT `FK_10D1B00C2CA1BD71`
>   FOREIGN KEY (`education_id`) REFERENCES `trainee_education` (`id`))

I know why my constraint is failing, nothing new. But I would like to get an exception so I could inform user that he cannot delete an object is he used it before to create relationship.

Comment: The exceptions says it's name is `ForeignKeyConstraintViolationException` not `PDOException`, are you sure the first extends the second? you should try to catch `ForeignKeyConstraintViolationException` and see. Or to be sure try to catch Exception, then you can figure out which class thrown as exception

Comment: @smarber \Exception was not working either, that is why I asked a question here. THank you for the input I will try it and will let you know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have the same situation, but I work with \Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException

```
try{

      $em->persist($question);
      $em->flush();
} catch (\Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException $e) {

      $exception_message = $e->getPrevious()->getCode();
    return $this->render('AppBundle:Errors:error.html.twig', array('error' => $exception_message)); 

}
```

I don't know if is the best solution, but works.

Comment: \Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException is deprecated in favor of \Doctrine\DBAL\Exception. Please update your answer.